# Select only first line from files under a directory in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to collect all the first line from the files under a directory using Pyspark i tried using

```
file=sc.wholeTextFiles("Location").map(lambda x: x[0]).collect()
```

but this is giving me list of files under directory.I want some thing like this below lets say i have two files

```
file1.csv     file2.csv
x,y,z          q,r,s
1,2,3          4,5,6
a,b,c          d,e,f
```

I want collect the first lines of the files {x,y,z} and {q,r,s}.Please help me, how can i get only first line from multiple files under a directory

Comment: I suspect you may want to groupBy - but you may first want to refine this question by adding a reproducible example and in particular a sample of the input and expected output data.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following:

```
def read_firstline(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        return f.readline()

# files is a list of filenames
rdd_of_firstlines = sc.parallelize(files).flatMap(read_firstline)
```