# Read first line of huge Json file with Spark using Pyspark

Tags: json, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, large-files

I'm pretty new to Spark and to teach myself I have been using small json files, which work perfectly. I'm using Pyspark with Spark 2.2.1 However I don't get how to **read in a** **single data line instead of the entire json file**.  I have been looking for documentation on this but it seems pretty scarce. I have to process a single large (larger than my RAM) json file (wikipedia dump: https://archive.org/details/wikidata-json-20150316) and want to do this in chuncks or line by line. I thought Spark was designed to do just that but can't find out how to do it and when I request the top 5 observations in a naive way I run out of memory. I have tried RDD .

```
SparkRDD= spark.read.json("largejson.json").rdd
SparkRDD.take(5)
```

and Dataframe

```
SparkDF= spark.read.json("largejson.json")
SparkDF.show(5,truncate = False)
```

So in short:

1) How do I **read** in just a **fraction of a large JSON file**? (Show first 5 entries)

2) How do I **filter a large JSON file line by line** to keep just the required results?

Also: I don't want to predefine the datascheme for this to work.

I must be overlooking something.

Thanks

Edit: With some help I have gotten a look at the first observation but it by itself is already too huge to post here so I'll just put a fraction of it here.

```
[
{
    "id": "Q1",
    "type": "item",
    "aliases": {
        "pl": [{
            "language": "pl",
            "value": "kosmos"
        }, {
            "language": "pl",
            "value": "\\u015bwiat"
        }, {
            "language": "pl",
            "value": "natura"
        }, {
            "language": "pl",
            "value": "uniwersum"
        }],
        "en": [{
            "language": "en",
            "value": "cosmos"
        }, {
            "language": "en",
            "value": "The Universe"
        }, {
            "language": "en",
            "value": "Space"
        }],
...etc
```

Comment: What is the structure of the document?

Comment: It's a wikipedia data dump: https://archive.org/details/wikidata-json-20150316

Comment: Please provide a sample in the question. I doubt anyone will download 4GB of data just to answer your question. And knowing the structure is important to understand the source of the failure.

Comment: That's exactly my own problem: I can't take a sample because I can't access the first few rows because I run out of memory because I don't know how to take in just a few rows instead of everything. :D. I would gladly like to give you a sample...thereby answering the biggest part my question :D

Comment: `head largejson.json` or `with open("large.json") as fr: s = fr.read(1000)` ? :) I suspect this is a single JSON document, and the answer will no can do and you'll have to write your own parsing / preparing logic.

Comment: Thanks for that snippet, I used it to get a grip on what the first observation looks like :) (that single entryby itself is already huge though). So...Spark doesn't allow you to process a large json file observation by observation? That surprises me, how does it handle big files than? You can't put everything in memory, that's just not realistic.

Answer (score 0):

That's very similar to [Select only first line from files under a directory in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803203/select-only-first-line-from-files-under-a-directory-in-pyspark)

Hence something like this should work :

```
def read_firstline(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        return f.readline()

# files is a list of filenames
rdd_of_firstlines = sc.parallelize(files).flatMap(read_firstline)
```